# Explanation of int? vs int

Tags: c#, variables, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between 'int?' and 'int' in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121680/whats-the-difference-between-int-and-int-in-c)

I've come across some code in C# that declares a variable as: `int? number`

What does the `?` mean and how does this differ from just: `int`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`int` cannot be `null`.

`int?` is an alias for the `Nullable<int>` struct, which you can set to `null`.

Comment: Note that `int?` is *also* a value type though... which contradicts the "by definition" of your first sentence...

Comment: I still disagree with your first sentence, as `int?` is a value type with a null value. You then talk about an "object" being null - whereas an *object* is never null, only a reference is... and a value type value isn't an object anyway.

Comment: You can't set int? to null, but you can assign null to it :)

Comment: These are some complex and interesting symantics #Programming makes me sweat all the time.

Answer (score 10):

`int?` is a shorthand for creating an instance of the generic `System.Nullable<T>` structure type. It allows you to make your variable nullable. Remember, given that the `<ValueType>?` syntax is a shorthand, you could declare your variables thus:

```
Nullable<int> i = 10;
```

Answer (score 5):

`int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>` which allows you to pretend that an integer can handle nulls.

```
int? foo = null;
```

It is useful for indicating a lack of value where you would previously have used a magic value (-1) in the past, and also useful when dealing with database columns that allow null entries.

For a quasi-in-depth look, a `Nullable<T>` (introduced in .NET 2.0) is simply a wrapper over a value type `T` that exposes two properties, `HasValue` and `Value`, where `HasValue` is a boolean that indicates if the value has been set and `Value` (obviously enough) returns the value. It is an error to access `Value` if `HasValue` is false. Therefore, to access `Value`, it is good form to check `HasValue` first. Additionally, if you simply want to normalize any non-values to default values (0 for numeric types), you can use the method `GetValueOrDefault()` without needing to check `HasValue`.

Note that although you appear to set `foo` to `null`, it's not *actually* null under normal usage scenarios. `null` is simply additional syntactic sugar for this type. The above line of code translates to

```
Nullable<int> foo = new Nullable<int>();
```

Initializing the variable in this fashion simply sets the `HasValue` property to false.

However, in situations involving boxing, the value will actually box to null if `HasValue` is false (it will otherwise box to `T`). Be aware of the consequences! For example, in:

```
int? foo = null; 
string bar = foo.ToString(); // this is fine, returns string.Empty
Type type = foo.GetType(); // blows up! GetType causes the value to box
                           // resulting in a NullReferenceException
```

That's a quick crash course. For more, visit the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

It's syntactic compiler sugar for `Nullable<int>`

Basically your number (or any other value type) can be null as well as it's value. You check for a value using the HasValue property. They can be cast into their value types (although this will fail if they're null) or you can use the Value property (again it will throw an exception if it is null)

One thing which usually appears to be overlooked when using nullable types is the GetValueOrDefault() method which returns default(T) if the object is null.

As @Kyle Trauberman points out in the comment you can indeed compare it to null instead of checking HasValue. The type itself is a value type with overriden equality methods so that much as it will never be null itself it will return true when compared to null if it doesn't have a value.

Comment: You can also use the normal `value == null` check instead of `HasValue`.

Answer (score 3):

A questionmark behind the declaration means that the variable is nullable.

Answer (score 2):

int? can be null where as int can not.

Reference  Nullable Types:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)