# C# type narrowing with if condition of nullable int

Tags: c#

The compiler complains that `int?` cannot be converted to `int`. I come from a typescript background where this would work because the compiler understands that `row` can't be `null`. Am I missing something or do I have to explicitly convert `row` to `int` with `int test = (int) row`?

```
int? row = GetRowOfCode(excel, code);
if (row != null)
{
  int test = row;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389437/explanation-of-int-vs-int

Comment: You can simplify the check with row.HasValue, and to copy the data: int test = row.Value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C#, once a variable is declared, it keeps the type it's declared as.

With reference types, like `string`, the nullable syntax is only supported by attributes and inference at compile-time, so `string?` is effectively the same as `string` besides some compiler hints. This would allow syntax like yours to work if you were working with a reference type.

But with value types, like `int`, the nullable type is literally a completely different type at run-time, so the value needs to be extracted from an `int?` in order to treat it like an `int`. You have to use a completely different variable to hold a strongly-typed `int?` versus `int`. That might look something like this:

```
if (row != null) // or row.HasValue
{
    int test = row.Value;
    // use `test`
}
```

With newer pattern matching syntax, you can do this instead:

```
if (row is int test)
{
   // use `test`
}
```