# Nullable Value Types in C# is Int32? REAALLY an Int32 -?

Tags: c#, types, nullable

So if I want to pass a nullable value type such as a Int32? into a method, I must tell the method param that it is a nullable.

```
public void foo(Int32? arg){...}
```

If I pass a regular Int32 into arg it works. But if I change it to

```
public void foo(Int32 arg){...}
```

and pass in a nullable it freaks out.

So my question is does the ? change the type of Int32 ?

Is there an Int32? object or does the ? just set a flag in Int32 and make it nullable?

Basically I am asking what is happening under the hood.

Comment: `Int32?` is a shortcut for `Nullable<Int32>`.  I would assume `Nullable` is a wrapper class.

Comment: "Duplicate" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121680/whats-the-difference-between-int-and-int-in-c

Answer (score 2):

`Int32?` is the short form for `Nullable<Int32>`, so these are two different types. An `Int32` can implicit casted to a `Nullable<Int32>`, but not the other way round.

In http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.100).aspx you can see the two operators:

```
Explicit(Nullable<T> to T): Returns the value of a specified Nullable<T> value.
Implicit(T to Nullable<T>): Creates a new Nullable<T> object initialized to a specified value.
```

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028830/c-sharp-nullableint-vs-int-is-there-any-difference

Answer (score 2):

the Nullable struct implement implicit conversion of type int to int?, whereas the other way is explicit so in your first case the conversion is implicit and the second you must make an explicit cast. here is an extruct of the code from Nulable struct:

```
    public static implicit operator T?(T value)
{
   return new T?(value);
}
public static explicit operator T(T? value)
{
   return value.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Int32?` is synonymous with `Nullable<Int32>` or just plain `Nullable<int>` or even `int?`

`int?` is a value type, and it can have the value `null`, which is why you can't pass it to a function argument of type `int` - what would happen if its value were `null`?