# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'

Tags: c#, int

I have this query:

```
int cid =  (from c in dc.Cs
                where c.id == cid
                select c.clientid).FirstOrDefault();

return cid;
```

where c.clientid is nullable. But I receive this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What do you expect the value of `cid` to be if either `c.clientid` is `null` in the first match, or if there are no matches?

Comment: `... .FirstOrDefault().Value;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thx that worked

Comment: You should read [what's the difference between 'int?' and 'int' in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121680/whats-the-difference-between-int-and-int-in-c)

Comment: @alxem No, it just turned a compiler error into a runtime error without actually fixing the problem.

Comment: Bear in mind that `FirstOrDefault` can be `null` in which case `.Value` will fault.  You should employ proper error checking prior to obtaining a value.

Comment: Why use an `int` in the first place, if you clearly should use a `Nullable<int>`?

Comment: @alxem it will throw an Exception if the query returns no items. But if you know for sure that situation will *never* happen, then use `.First();` instead of `FirstOrDefault().Value;` (functionally equivalent and obviously shorter code).

Comment: @Polyfun If `clientid` was an `int` then the OP wouldn't be getting this error. Since they're getting this error, it must be an `int?`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `int?` *can* be `null` while `int` *can't*. That's why the compiler *complains*: what should it assign to `cid` when the query returns `null`. You can try providing some *default value* in case of `null`:

```
int cid = (  from c in dc.Cs
            where c.id == cid
           select c.clientid)
  .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0; //TODO: put the right default value instead of 0

return cid;
```

which means return `0` in case of `null` (please, notice that you have *two* possibilities: 1. 1st item `c.clientid` is `null`; 2. `dc.Cs` when filtered is *empty*) and `int?.Value` otherwise

Comment: @Samir Aguiar: sorry, but in case of *empty*  `.FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` and, finally the *single* default value. In your syntax we have *two* defaults: when 1st value is null and when `IEnumerable<T>` is empty. It's a problem when default is `0`, but it is when it is, say `-1`