# Difficulty in understanding class Property declaration

Tags: c#

I was going through a class library in one of our projects.

i came across statements like `public int? variablename`

What does this mean..I am going to create classes for new application refering current

application .

So ,i would like to know what it is  and in which scenarios we can use and is it not

possible to avoid it

Comment: That is a nullable type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It's shorthand for `Nullable<int>`..

Comment: Google for 
nullable int in C#"

Comment: which part of this don't you understand? the `?` in `int?`?

Comment: @Stephen: I'm not sure that doesn't count as a complete answer. I'd have certainly upvoted it if it had been...

Comment: @Chris, thanks I'll toss it in the mix and see what happens.

Comment: I am confused about using ? in the property declaration..i have not used it before..in which scenarios we are required to use it..and is it not possible to avoid it

Answer (score 2):

int? means that it is "nullable". Being nullable allows you to have null values in your int.

Check out this link if you need to understand a bit more,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28VS.80%29.aspx

[How do nullable types work in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110229/how-do-nullable-types-work-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is a shortcut for `Nullable<>` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

`int?` is the same as `Nullable<int>`

Answer (score 1):

That is a nullable type [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This means that the variable is nullable