# Check if integer == null

Tags: c#, if-statement, null, integer

I want to check if my Listentry = null but I don't know how.

Note:
ID is a Integer

Here is my Code

```
if(MeineGaeste[i].ID !=null)
{
    i++;
}
else
{
    MeinGast.ID = i++;
    test = false;
}
```

Comment: Integers cannot be null. Is it declared as `int` or `int?` ?

Comment: If the `ID` member is __declared__ as `int`, then the comparison `ID != null` is meaningless. You will get a compile-time warning about it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's missing vital details like the data type of the variable in question. It also doesn't help that the presented code invokes invalid logic in the `else` condition (attempts to increment a `null` value, which should error out if invoked, assuming it compiles). In other words, it just doesn't make enough sense to be able to understand the author's intentions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As stated, an int cannot be null. If a value is not set to it, then the default value is zero. You can do a check for 0 if that is what you think it is being set to...

Otherwise if you are keen on avoiding nullable integers, you would have to turn it into a string and then perform the check.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(ID.ToString());
```

Which returns a boolean so you can stick it into an if statement.

Comment: I can't make sense of your answer. If you avoid `int?` (which means `ID` is an `int`), then `ID.toString()` could never produce the empty string, making the check always false. How does it help to convert anything to a string in that case? You still can't detect a missing value if `0` is a valid value otherwise.

Comment: @jpmc26 You are correct that an *unassigned* ID variable would be zero and would resolve to a string as "0". Answer should be:  ID.ToString() == "0" or something like that.

Comment: And what advantage does that have over just checking the value directly with `ID == 0`? Converting to a string makes no sense here; there's no functional reason to do so. And this answer still does not solve the issue of how to represent or detect a missing value.

Comment: Even worse, `ID.ToString()` would actually error out if `ID` *can* be `null`.

Comment: I didnt say there was an advantage. The "answer" is that an int cannot be null and you can do a check for zero. Converting to a string is just a suggestion that may or may not be helpful, but to a noob asking this question, they may not know about this method.

Comment: "The 'answer' is that an int cannot be null and you can do a check for zero." Then why does your answer spend more words and space on converting to a string? "Converting to a string is just a suggestion that may or may not be helpful, but to a noob asking this question, they may not know about this method." That statement implies there is some functional use for converting it to string *for solving this particular problem.* Unless you can explain how it helps solve *this particular problem*, mentioning it here will only confuse the inexperienced developers you're talking about.

Comment: int? i = null; Null it is.

Answer (score 10):

An `int` cannot be null. On the other hand a nullable int, `int?`, can be. That being said the check that you want to do is meaningless.

Changing the type of `ID` from `int` to `int?`, the check you do has a meaning and the compiler wouldn't complain about it.

Comment: Thank ypu for you answer. But how I can use int? in my program.?

Comment: Thank you for you answer but hiw I can use int? in my program? This is a litle Piece of my schoolproject.

Comment: @You are welcome. That depends on what you want to do. To be honest with, I don't get what are trying to achieve. However, the first thing you  might have to do, as I can infer from your post, is to change the type of ID from `int` to `int?`

Comment: so?

private int? _ID;
        public int? ID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            set { _ID = value; }
        }

Comment: Exactly ! By the way since you don't have any logic in the setter or in the getter, you could eliminate the above to the following: `public int? ID { get; set; }`

Comment: I know but it is a Piece of a schoolwork :) I Need to do this

Comment: The result is always true because an integer never can be null

Comment: How is that possible? Since the type of ID is a nullable int, ID can be null.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this ID.HasValue it return true when there is a value and false if null

Comment: Awesome answer! That helped out my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great comment, you helped me overcome a potential headache. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As a normal `int` type is a value type, it can not be `null`.

You can use the nullable type `int?` for the property `ID` which is basically a struct, that allows `null` or any `int` value. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.140).aspx) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110229/how-do-nullable-types-work-in-c) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121680/whats-the-difference-between-int-and-int-in-c) for additional documentation.

If it is not possible to change the type of the `ID` property, a workaround might be to choose an integer as marker value which is guaranteed not appear in your model (for example `Int32.MinValue`, as most generated IDs seem to be positive integers). **Don't do this if you don't have to, as this will most likely lead to errors.** I would a least recommend to throw an exception if you serialize models with that marker value.

Comment: Thank you, i know that, my Question was not perfect.. I Need a alternative.